# ¿Por que demora tanto en devolver datos MySql remota usando Vb.net 2019 a traves de MySql.Data.MySqlClient?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, net

estoy conectando desde mi aplicación en VB.net a una BD en Mysql utilizando **MySql.Data.MySqlClient** que esta remotamente en mi servidor y no entiendo por que demora tanto (5 a 6 segundos) en entregarme los datos por que son solo 2 o 3 registros.
Mi conexion es buena y mi PC tambien lo és. Estoy utilizando la version Comunitty de VS 2019.
Algo que me pueda ayudar para mejorar esto por favor ?

Esta es mi Clase que gestiona la conexión .....

```
Private Shared _FECHASERVIDOR As Date
Public Shared Property FECHASERVIDOR As Date
    Get
        Return _FECHASERVIDOR
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Date)
        _FECHASERVIDOR = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Shared Sub ObtenerFechaServidor()
    Try 'Select * From NOMBRE_TABLA order by  Convert(DATE, campo_fecha)
        If Not Acceso.Conectado Then
            Acceso.AbrirConexion()
            Acceso.adaptador = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT NOW() AS CurrentDateTime", Acceso.Conexion)
            Acceso.ds = New DataSet
            Acceso.adaptador.Fill(Acceso.ds)
            If Acceso.ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                FECHASERVIDOR = CDate(Acceso.ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0))
            Else
                FECHASERVIDOR = Today.Date
            End If
            Acceso.Conectado = True
        Else
            Debug.Print("cerrar")              
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(Err.Description)
        MsgBox("Se produjo el siguiente error: " & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error N° " & Err.Number)
        Acceso.Conectado = False
    End Try
End Sub
Public Shared Function Iniciar(ByVal cadena As String) As Boolean
    Try
        ObtenerFechaServidor()
        ComparaFechas()
        Acceso.comando = New MySqlCommand(cadena, Acceso.Conexion)
        Acceso.comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?FECHA", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = FECHASERVIDOR
        Acceso.adaptador = New MySqlDataAdapter(Acceso.comando)
        Acceso.ds = New DataSet
        Acceso.adaptador.Fill(Acceso.ds)
        If Acceso.ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 1 Then
            user_id = CInt(Acceso.ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0))                     'ID
            user_nombre = Acceso.ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1).ToString              'USUARIO
            user_razonsocial = Acceso.ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2).ToString         'RAZON SOCIAL
            user_telefono = Acceso.ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(6).ToString            'TELEFONO
            user_email = Acceso.ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3).ToString               'EMAIL
            user_estado = CInt(Acceso.ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(4))                 'ESTADO
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
        Acceso.Conexion.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(Err.Description)
        Console.WriteLine(Err.Number)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
Private Shared Sub ComparaFechas()
    Dim FechaPC As Date = Date.Today
    Dim DateWeb As Date = FECHASERVIDOR
    Dim dateOnlyWEB As Date = DateWeb.Date
    Dim dateOnlyPC As Date = FechaPC.Date
    If dateOnlyPC.ToString("d") = dateOnlyWEB.ToString("d") Then
        'la fecha es correcta
        Exito = True
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Sin `ORDER BY` ¿tarda menos?

Comment: No lo estoy utilizando!

Comment: Usa la clase Stopwatch para comprobar en que parte del codigo tienes el retardo. Por el Visual Studio no es, quedaría ver la sencencia SQL que usas, conexión, incluso el router, con alguna proteccion DDos...

Comment: Nada estraño en el Sql algo asi nomas "Select * Empresas Where id = id_Empresa". y no tengo ninguna proteccion en mi router. He estado leyendo en distintos lugares y me recomiendan utilizar php que es mucho mas rapido por que trabaja del lado del Servidor. En cambio de este modo directo se retarda. Pende q era por q se cerraba la conexion cada vez q terminaba la peticion pero modifique eso y dejo la conexion abierta y la segunda vez que consulta es lo mismo.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JG9T46s.png

Comment: he usado StopWach como me indicas y creo q el problema esta en otro lado ya que como se puede ver en la imagen cdo solicito las empresas de la BD si bien solo hay una de muestra demora 504 milisegundos.  No se si puedo poner el enlace de la iamgen aca https://pasteboard.co/JG9T46s.png